# Subtracting duration from dateTime in Cocoa's NSXML XQuery

Tags: cocoa, xquery, nsxml

I have the following XQuery code, which from my reading of the O'Reilly XQuery book seems like it should work:

```
let $now := current-dateTime()
let $month :=  xs:dayTimeDuration("P30D")
let $month_ago := $now - $month 
return $month_ago
```

It works fine in this live XQuery interpreter:
http://try.zorba-xquery.com/
But in Cocoa's NSXML it returns the XQuery error "Invalid type for operator."

Is there something I don't understand about Cocoa's implementation of XQuery?

Answer (score 3):

You should use `xs:dayTimeDuration` or `xs:yearMonthDuration` for wich are defined [substracting operators](http://www.w3.org/TR/2007/REC-xpath-functions-20070123/#func-subtract-yearMonthDuration-from-dateTime).

As proof, this XQuery:

```
let $now := current-dateTime()
let $month :=  xs:dayTimeDuration("P30D")
let $month_ago := $now - $month
return $month_ago
```

Output:

```
2011-03-23T14:32:47.156-03:00
```

Tested on Saxon, Altova, XQSharp.

From http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/#mapping, this is the operator mapping:

> ```
> Operator | Type(A)              | Type(B)              | Function  
> A - B    | numeric              | numeric              | op:numeric-subtract(A, B)  
> A - B    | xs:date              | xs:date              | op:subtract-dates(A, B)   
> A - B    | xs:date              | xs:yearMonthDuration | op:subtract-yearMonthDuration-from-date(A, B)  
> A - B    | xs:date              | xs:dayTimeDuration   | op:subtract-dayTimeDuration-from-date(A, B)  
> A - B    | xs:time              | xs:time              | op:subtract-times(A, B)   
> A - B    | xs:time              | xs:dayTimeDuration   | op:subtract-dayTimeDuration-from-time(A, B)     
> A - B    | xs:dateTime          | xs:dateTime          | op:subtract-dateTimes(A, B)  
> A - B    | xs:dateTime          | xs:yearMonthDuration | op:subtract-yearMonthDuration-from-dateTime(A, B)    
> A - B    | xs:dateTime          | xs:dayTimeDuration   | op:subtract-dayTimeDuration-from-dateTime(A, B)    
> A - B    | xs:yearMonthDuration | xs:yearMonthDuration | op:subtract-yearMonthDurations(A, B)`
> ```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried replacing the second line with:

`let $month :=  xs:dayTimeDuration("P30D")`

and got the same error. Any suggestions?

Comment: And thanks for expanding the answer, but as I said, it still doesn't work in Cocoa.

Answer (score 1):

This feature is an XPath 2.0 it seems. Maybe your processor doesn't support this?

Executing your query [here](http://try.zorba-xquery.com/) shows that it is indeed correct. So, with zorba it works...

Comment: I'm using Cocoa's NSXML, which according to the documentation "includes support for XQuery 1.0 and XPath 2.0." So maybe this is a problem with NSXML's XPath implementation? I've edited the question with this information.